# Xamarin ProgressBar doesn't show animation

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have a problem. I am trying to use a ProgressBar, so I created this code:

Here is the RelativeLayout:

And here is the c# code:

```
ProgressBar progressBar;

public Preivew()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    ContentView LoadingView = new ContentView
    {
        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
        BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent
    };

    progressBar= new ProgressBar
    {
        ProgressColor = Color.FromHex("#3897F0"),
        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
        HeightRequest = 30,
        Progress = 0.0
    };

    RelativeLoadingLayout.Children.Add(LoadingView,
            Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) =>
            {
                return (0);
            }),
            Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) =>
            {
                return (0);
            }),
            Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) =>
            {
                return parent.Width;
            }), Constraint.RelativeToParent((parent) =>
            {
                return parent.Height;
            }));

    LoadingView.Content = progressBar;
}

protected override async void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();

    UpdateProgressBar(0.8, 2000).Wait();
}

async Task UpdateProgressBar(double Progress, uint time)
{
    MemeProgressBar.ProgressTo(Progress, time, Easing.Linear);
}
```

But when the page loads, the ProgressBar is already loaded, without animations. I created a custom Task which should set the animation of loading.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `UpdateProgressBar` is async and not awaited, so you'll land on `progressBar.Progress = 1` without delay

Comment: Okay, I changed my code at the bottom, but still nothing! See code above

Comment: The problem is still the same. `Task.Run()` still executes the code without waiting for it. The best solution would probably be to put this into an async [`OnAppearing`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.page.onappearing?view=xamarin-forms) and properly await it

Comment: Okay, but what if I want to move the progressbar when I completed a webcall or something. There must be a function who can change the progress?

Comment: Try updating your version of Xamarin.Forms. there was an issue with animations in the 4.2 version of Forms.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59422458/xamarin-forms-crashes-after-update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Make sure you are not on Xamarin.Forms version 4.2

You could check the following code

#### in xaml

```
<ProgressBar x:Name="progressBar" Progress="0.0" BackgroundColor="LightBlue" WidthRequest="200" HeightRequest="50"/>
```

#### in code behind

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
  base.OnAppearing();

  UpdateProgressBar(0.8, 5000);
}

async Task UpdateProgressBar(double Progress, uint time)
{
  progressBar.ProgressTo(Progress, time, Easing.Linear);
}
```

[image]

Comment: I have no idea, but it doesn't work on my device.... There is no annimation!

Comment: The difference is that I add the ProgressBar programmaticaly, see code above

Comment: Its weird, becaue I added a blank page with only your code, but again no animation.... It looks like my android doesn't want to animate things!?

Comment: I think the animation may be broken on Android? The above works on iOS but not on my Android simulator.

Comment: Edit: After updating to XF latest nuget, it now works on Android. Seems there was an issue with animations on 4.2 version of X.Forms:

Comment: I updated it to 4.3.0..... 4.4.0 is also available, but my app crashes on that version!

Answer (score -1):

I can see that you are setting the progress to 1 manually, so of course it will always be 1. also ass @BiesiGrr said you probably want to handle that code on the OnAppearing life cycle method, because, InitilizeComponents() doesn't really render the page it merely initializes the objects defined in XAML, so the progress bar might finish updating before the page is even rendered.

If you need to execute this code after a certain task is finished try using the ContinueWith() method or just await for it, your call, I prefer the async await pattern personally

Comment: I updated my code again, because still no animation!

Comment: I can see from your update that you actually need to take a look at this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/await

a little tip calling the Wait() method -opposing to use the await operator- will case the code to be executed on the main thread i.e. the UI thread, which would in turn freeze the app, so to wrap up -of course you are not seeing any animation-